# Got error "Not a WAVE file - no RIFF header"

Tags: c#, wav, naudio, speechsynthesizer

This is how I speak "Hello" using `SpeechSynthesizer` , convert with NAudio `WaveFormatConversionStream` and read it again .

And I got the error

> Not a WAVE file - no RIFF header

```
 int count = sourceFiles.Count;   
    WaveFileReader[] reader = new WaveFileReader[count];    

   var _wavStream = new MemoryStream();
                            using (SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer())
                            {
                                synth.SetOutputToWaveStream(_wavStream);
                                synth.Speak("Hello");
                                _wavStream.Position = 0;
                                int outRate = 44100;
                                var outFormat = new WaveFormat(outRate, 16, 1);
                                using (var resampler = new WaveFormatConversionStream(outFormat, new WaveFileReader(_wavStream)))
                                {
                          reader[i] = new WaveFileReader(resampler); <====GotTheErrorHere
```

How can I fix it ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The speech synthesizer has not made a WAV file, so there is no RIFF header. instead of `WaveFileReader` you should be using `RawSourceWaveStream` and passing in the memory stream and the correct `WaveFormat` that the speech synthesizer is outputting .

Comment: I've tried with this  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4237282/1427849 but it's still give me same error , would you please help me with code ?